Run kubectl on Jenkins slave node which is a Kubernetes pod
Recently I have successfully setup Jenkins slave on Kubernetes pod. Below test job works well.
podTemplate(yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  containers:
  - name: maven
    image: maven:latest
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: node
    image: node:16-alpine3.12
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
"""
)  

{
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Build Petclinic Java App') {
      git url: 'https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git', branch: 'main'
      container('maven') {
        sh 'mvn -B -ntp clean package -DskipTests'
      }
    }
    stage('Run on Node') {
      container('node') {
        sh 'npm version'
      }
    }
  }
}

Now I want to deploy the image I built to a kubernetes cluster. So I need to run kubectl inside the slave node. How can I achieve this? I believe in all the containers, i.e. 'maven', 'node' or 'jnlp', they don't have kubectl cli available. Should I deploy a 4th container  with kubectl?

Also, what about I need to run a docker build command to build an image. Do I need to create another container with docker cli in it?

You could either deploy a fourth container that has the kubectl command line in it and use service accounts to authorize deployments to a different cluster, or you could create you work image that bundles all the tools you want into one image and use that. As for docker, you can use the official docker image to run a docker in docker setup.

thanks!
I tried another way which is to setup kubectl command inside an existing maven container so that I dont need to deploy a 4th container. Is it something you recommend or any known risks for this option?

@Steve That is perfectly fine
